# Blackberry BitmapField focus-unfocus prob

Tags: blackberry, bitmap, onfocus

I want to set a text in a specific label on focus of an `BitmapField`, and reset the text on unfocus. I am using the following code:

```
final BitmapField tab1 = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/icon1.png"), FIELD_BOTTOM | BitmapField.FOCUSABLE) {
    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
        // the simplies way to draw a rectangle and this will be the
        // focus

    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        // write here your code what you want to run the user clicks to
        // the bitmap
        // try something like this
        Dialog.alert("Code for tab1");
        return true;
    }

    public void setFocus(){
        super.setFocus();
        selectedLabel.setText("tab1");      
    }

    public void onUnfocus(){
        super.onUnfocus();
        selectedLabel.setText("");  
    }

};
```

But focus is changing properly, but label is not setting at all. Where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override `onFocus(int direction)` instead of `setFocus()`

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    super.onFocus(direction);
    selectedLabel.setText("tab1");
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    super.onUnfocus();
    selectedLabel.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onfocus()` & `onUnfocus()` method and replace your `LabelField` in both method with `Invalidate()` option .